# What do I need to import to use a theme in FullCalendar?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I would like to implement the 'slate' theme in React FullCalendar.
I assume you set themeSystem='slate' but am unsure if the slate theme is a bootstrap theme or one included with FullCalendar's CSS, so I am not sure what to import to make the theme work. Either the documentation on the theme is lacking or I just cannot find it for the life of me!

```
                    <FullCalendar
                        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, momentTimezonePlugin]}
                        headerToolbar={{
                            left: 'prev,next,today',
                            center: 'title',
                            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                        }}
                        initialView='timeGridWeek'
                        selectable={true}
                        selectMirror={true}
                        themeSystem='slate'
                        dayMaxEvents={false}
                        weekends={true}
                        timeZone={time_zone} 
                        events={scheduledEvents}
                        eventClick={handleShowUpdateEvent}
                        select={handleShowCreateEvent}
                        eventContent={renderEventContent}
                        eventChange={UpdateEvent}
                        displayEventTime={true}
                    />
```

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out? I installed the Bootswatch themes into my application per @sanish's recommendation, but FullCalendar is still not recognizing the theme.

Answer (score 1):

The themes you see is coming from https://bootswatch.com/

Those are the themes being applied when you change the theme name here,

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/theme-chooser-demo

Check bootwatch documents for adding the theming you need.